# Get timestamp, date and time fields in date format in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to plot date histograms in kibana 5 for each day. Therefore, I want the x-axis to be just the time. Right now, I have a @timestamp field, which has the datetime captured as `2017-04-17T20:12:47.221Z`. I'm capturing it from a timestamp field in a csv file, which looks like this:`[4/17/17 20:12:47:221]`.

This is my current logstash config code which takes data from a csv file:

```
filter {
if [type] == "Error_file" {
    csv {
            columns => ["timestamp", "message"]
    }
    date {
            match => ["timestamp", "[M/dd/yy HH:mm:ss:SSS]"]
            add_field => { "Date" => "%{+M/dd/yy}" }
            add_field => { "Time" => "%{+HH:mm:ss:SSS}" }
    }

}
```

However, the date and time are getting captured as string and I'm not able to plot the date histogram. If there is a way in Kibana to directly plot the above histogram without capturing data and time separately, I can work with that too.

Have just started using the ELK stack so I would appreciate if you can provide some explanation along with the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to have separate date/time fields. Why not simply working on the `dateFormat` pattern in the [advanced options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html)?

Comment: Can you explain pls? I'm new to Kibana

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the Date and Time fields again using the date filter like below.

```
date {
   match => [ "Date", "M/dd/yy"]
   target => "Date"
}
date {
  match => [ "Time", "HH:mm:ss:SSS"]
  target => "Time"
}
```